# Debugging java swing application in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, awt

I have a large application made in java swing. Its a children drawing app. I need to put some restrictions, for example, if they draw a rectangle, then they can't link it to a circle on the same page. In most of the classes below are the packages imported:

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.ButtonGroup;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JCheckBoxMenuItem;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.event.MenuEvent;
import javax.swing.event.MenuListener;
```

I am able to run it in eclipse. What I want to do is to understand what code is getting called when we draw a rectangle, then which exact code gets called when we draw a line to link it to a circle etc.

Is it possible to do with eclipse? Please note that there are 2300 java classes in it overall and there is no documentation. To make matters worse, I am new to java. Please can someone help? If any other suggestion apart from eclipse, that will be fine too.

Comment: Not easier. I'd be looking for appropriate input listeners (`MouseListener`, `KeyboardListener` and/or Key bindings). I'd then try and understand which component is actually performing the rendering so you can back track up through the model to better understand where decisions are been made and when

Comment: I'd recommend getting started with [Creating a GUI With JFC/Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html), [How to write a mouse listener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mouselistener.html), [Performing Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) and [Painting in Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html)

Comment: I think it should be possible, just that I am not aware. Please look at the FLOW debugger at http://findtheflow.io/      I need something similar for eclipse. As my application can't be run in intelliJ

Comment: Then try the [stand alone version instead](http://findtheflow.io/docs/doc_intellij.html#_how_to_use_flow_standalone_version)

Comment: It doesn't work anymore. Thats why I was looking for something similar or simpler

Comment: Took a little bit of effort, but Flow seems to work okay for me

Comment: To find the code of a particular function you can use the differential code coverage of Eclipse: launch the application in coverage mode, reset already collected coverage data, execute the function and dump the coverage data. The code executed by the function is shown as covered. See [this video which shows this in action](https://youtu.be/p_mVa9iNmzk?t=17m41s).

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out the hard way. Hope this solution helps someone very new to Java and needs to debug/fix some issue.

What one needs to understand is that a Java application starts with a class that has a method main() as:

```
    class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println("Hello");
    }
   }
```

What you can do is first find this class, put some debug messages beginning from this class and observe how the flow is as you use the application. This is the only approach that worked for as I was debugging a java app that had no documentation.